# HOW TO request URL change some numbers every time?

Tags: python, function, url

I have this URL  for example:

http://web.ca.com/y/d.ASP?id=1

i would like to  request  this URL every time with change the id every time i reqested.

how to do that by Python.

> result
>
> http://web.ca.com/y/d.ASP?id=2
>
> http://web.ca.com/y/d.ASP?id=3
>
> http://web.ca.com/y/d.ASP?id=4

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific with your problem? What have you tried so far and what error did you encounter?

Comment: Maybe it will be easyer to change it in PHP

Answer (score 0):

You could use `requests`.

```
import requests

for x in range(0,10): # Here you define the amount of tries you're going to check    
   r = requests.get('http://web.ca.com/y/d.ASP?id={}'.format(x)) # this would be the loop value    
   print(r.status_code) # this would be the http response code
```